# How to get from old town Cartagena to the airport for a very early flight?

Tags: airport-transfer, colombia, cartagena

Having a very early flight leaving Cartagena airport shortly after 6 AM, what options are available to get there from the old town?

Since it is an international flight, I expect to aim for arrival around 4 AM, but please confirm if that is not too early. It happened to me elsewhere that I arrived with the requested anticipation and the airport had not opened yet! What is a reasonable time to leave for the airport then?

Comment: Cartagena in Spain or Cartagena in Colombia?

Comment: Colombia, as per the tag.

Comment: I apparently need to be more observant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (tourist) hostel in the old town of Cartagena in Colombia can arrange a taxi for you at any time. I would think any hotel can as well.

If you're on your own, you could try your best at calling a taxi company  and arranging a pickup. But, asking for help at one of the tourist offices would probably be a better bet. Unless your Spanish is good.

If you are comfortable walking through the old town in the middle of the night, taxis are waiting for rides on the eastern corner of the old town, near [Monumento India-Catalina](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/La+India+Catalina/@10.4239303,-75.548798,985m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x972d53a6e170089c!6m1!1e1?hl=en).

I've never been to the airport in Cartagena, but considering it's not a small town, I would think that aiming for 4AM would not be a bad idea. But, that's speculation.

Comment: Turns out 4 AM was too early since immigration opens at 5 AM and they were still setting up the ticketing booths when I got there at 4:45 AM *this* morning. Good advice on the taxi though.